# Resize picture, what should I use?

Tags: javascript, css

Soo, I have seen that I can use both javascript and css to resize my pictures to fit the browser. 
Which one should I use, is there any pros / cons?
Would appreciate and example of what I could look like aswell.

Best regards
Lost boy

Comment: Usually, resizing an image with JavaScript, means using JavaScript to set some CSS values on an `<img>`.  To resize an image with JavaScript  and *not* CSS, you'd have to load it into a canvas and play with it that way, which would be much more difficult, and probably overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JavaScript's `resize` event, there will always be some delay which could cause horizontal scrollbars to flicker on your page.

So use CSS. `width:100%` works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for a good and quick answer! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I've voted to close, but regardless:

CSS.  It's lighter weight, doesn't require javascript, runs without javascript enabled, and will render faster (javascript will have to wait for the image to load, while css will not).

Comment: Even tho you voted to close I really appreciate that you answered the question!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are doing.

If you just want an image that is 600px tall by 800px wide (or is 10% of the width of the browser, or fills the entire page), then use CSS.

If you are already doing things with javascript and want the images to adjust on another condition, then you can use javascript to resize them.

In short: if you already are using javascript, go ahead.  If you aren't, CSS will do for most simple purposes.

Comment: Thank you for a good and quick answer! Appreciate it!